# interfacing arduino coordinator with ethernet shield and xbee stacked and a node station with an arduino and xbee

Tags: arduino, xbee

this please. 
How do you connect or create the interface from an xbee all the way to the web for it to work. This is a sample description.

web←ethernet shield←arduino←xbee --xbee→arduino→led

Can somebody please give me a sample code for this to work?

Comment: Take a look at http://examples.digi.com/ for a starting point, you'll be combining multiple examples.  Also the XBee Internet Gateway is a useful program to replace the Arduino with Ethernet shield, but requires Python.

Answer (score 1):

the ethernet shield doesn’t pass the ICSP pins through to the next layer hence the XBee shield has nothing to plug into.

try this:

http://home-automation-upenn.blogspot.com/2012/04/using-ethernet-shield-and-xbee-shield.html

http://www.makechronicles.com/2012/03/10/arduino-project-5-adding-a-stackable-icsp-header-to-the-arduino-ethernet-shield-micro-sdr3-version/

Answer (score 0):

The Sparkfun Xbee shield works fine.  It doesn't use the ICSP pins.